# Error Build APK Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'

Tags: java, android, gradle

Error Bulid APK
What problem in this code? Firebase? I try clean and rebuild. But I have this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class

My app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp.over.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        multiDexEnabled true
        }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.mvpotter:kladr-api-client:0.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}









apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

What I need doing?

Comment: have you tried to invalidate cache and restart and after that clean and rebuild?

Comment: i try. It is didn`t help

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me once, the problem specifically was

`duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class`

so I checked my dependencies and found that I got multiple declaration of dependencies, so go in to you libs folder and check if there is a jar file that is also declared in your dependencies

```
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

most probably one of these are already in your `libs` folder:

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.mvpotter:kladr-api-client:0.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: I doesn`t contains directory libs.

Comment: what is the content of your `libs`?

Comment: I can 2 libs in folder .idea javax_inject_1.xml and javax_inject_2_5_0_b32.xml. Maybe it is error? But I doesn`t known what library generated this

Comment: yea that's it, remove one of them.

Comment: If I remove one of them then I rebuild project xml file create again

Answer (score 0):

Problem in Maven. 
Maven can`t be include in Gradle.